# loosing css properties in jquery-mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

Im using jquery-mobile.

 in the panel menu i have a link that when user clicks on it the page loads but it looses its css properties and gives me a dirty page!

```
<div data-role="panel">
<ul>
<li><a href="login_page.html">Login</a></li>
.
.
.
</ul>
</div>
```

In login_page.html i have:

```
<ul class="forms">
<li><input type="text"></li>
.
.
.
</ul>
```

and in css:

```
.forms{
list-style:none;
background-color:red;
}
.forms li
{
display:inline;
}
```

**Note:** *When I refresh the page the css properties comes back.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `jquery-mobile` and the other pages might be written by other web languages.
If by refreshing page it gets fixed so you're probebly lucked in a frame,and you should use `target="_top"` to escape it:

```
<a href="example.com" target="_top"></a>
```

Comment: Yes you were right when i refreshed the page it got fixed but now it works